# How to get session object in mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

In our code we need to pass HttpContext to get session object with this approach there is no issue in controller, So my question is how can I get session object in view page.

The below AppSessionData object is placed in session

```
public class AppSessionData
{
    public int user1 { get; set; } = -1;
    public int user2 { get; set; } = -1;
}
```

user defined method to get session object
`SessionHelper.GetAppData(HttpContext);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SessionHelper.GetAppData(Session["SessionStringIndex"]);
```

Replace `SessionStringIndex` with what you declare on your session e.g.

```
Session["SeesionStringIndex"] = YourAppSessionData();
```

Comment: So you are saying that is without passing Http context right

Comment: Yes. You can access it via Session syntax.

Comment: As per the application design I have to access session object only by passing Httpcontext .right now getting  common fields in session data  from controller to view  I am passing with View bag. Are there any alternative approaches any idea on that?